# Multiple Telnet sessions running parallel with vbscript

Tags: android, batch-file, vbscript, telnet

I call from a .bat script 7 vbscripts to start Telnet sessions with 7 Android Emulators.The problem is that in the end all vbscripts write to the same Telnet session. I am new to scripting so please help.

begin.bat

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,7) DO (
   ::start emulator
   emulator -avd em%%G
   :: Open a Telnet window
   timeout /t 60 /nobreak >NUL

   set /A "_myport= 5552+2*%%G"
   timeout /t 1 /nobreak >NUL
   telnet.exe localhost !_myport!
   ::run script
   cscript SendKeys.vbs)
```

SendKeys.vbs

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.sleep 50

Dim max,min
max=100
min=1
Randomize
battery_level= Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)

OBJECT.SendKeys "power capacity "
OBJECT.SendKeys battery_level
OBJECT.SendKeys "{ENTER}"



'Xml stuff for getting the coordinates
Set objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

objXML.async = False
objXML.Load ("C:\Users\basilhs\Downloads\alimos-omonoia.xml")




Set point = objXML.getElementsByTagName("trkpt")

For i = 0 To point.length - 1
    Set subNodes = point(i)
    OBJECT.SendKeys "geo fix "
    OBJECT.SendKeys subNodes.getAttribute("lon")
    OBJECT.SendKeys " "
    OBJECT.SendKeys subNodes.getAttribute("lat")
    OBJECT.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    WScript.Sleep 5000
Next
    OBJECT.SendKeys "exit{ENTER}"
```

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me, how people would take the awkward/flaky `SendKeys` approach to scripting `telnet` instead of using a [`telnet`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) that's actually scriptable...

Comment: Thanks for the reply but can you be more specific please, I am new to scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Look up `AppActivate`

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

         WshShell.Run "calc"
         WshShell.Run "notepad"

         WScript.Sleep 100

         Msgbox WshShell.AppActivate("Save As")

         WScript.Sleep 100

         Msgbox WshShell.AppActivate("Calculator")

         WScript.Sleep 100
         Msgbox WshShell.AppActivate("Notepad")

         WScript.Sleep 100
         Msgbox WshShell.AppActivate("Calculator")

         WScript.Sleep 100
```

and here's another sample

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

If WSHShell.AppActivate("Calculator")=False then 
    WshShell.Run "C:\windows\System32\calc.exe", 1, false 
End If
```